# How to disable automatic forward from gmail with no password

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

Is it possible to disable automatic forward from a gmail address (that I do not know the password and I have no access to) to my email address?

Answer (score 2):

Use filters to process the emails from that address. You can slap a label and archive the email; or delete them; or treat them a spam. The choice is up to you, depending on why they are being forwarded and your relationship to the owner of the address.

Comment: I know all those possibilities (I automatically delete all of them), but I need to know if is it possible to disable the automatic forwarding to avoid any discussions

Comment: If you don't have access to the account, and can't get access you can only block them.